# Ngrx store organization

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, state-management

In my application, I have an `InventoryModule` that is responsible for showing a list of items, add and display details of an item, add and display details of a kit (which is a group of items that should be sold together with a special price tag).

Inventory is a feature of the main application and the `InventoryModule` has 3 submodules: `InventoryKitModule`, `InventoryItemModule` and `InventoryListModule`.

All these 3 modules are then composed by a few subcomponents grouped in a main module component that acts has an orchestrator of these subcomponents.

I'm using NgRx and I'm trying to figure out the best way to organize my store, but all examples over the internet use pretty simple projects, where a store composed by a single list of entities is usually enough.

From my point of view I can see that I have two different groups of actions: 
1) actions that communicate to the API 
2) actions that control component specific states, like showing a list of something inside the component, changing the state of a button, and so on.

If I create a feature store using the Store.ForFeature(...) I'll have to create all actions/reducers in a single file and that means a lot of actions because I'll actually be mixing actions needed for three different screens.

I think that the best option would be to create a feature store with all actions that will need to call the API and 3 subfeatures stores that will be responsible for managing the state of the three modules in the `InventoryModule`.

Is it possible to create a feature store for a feature that already has a store? Does it even make any sense?

Comment: I think this is a good video if you haven't seen it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY to deal with separating your actions. Since that is where everything really starts.

Comment: Thats an amazing video, I have already watched it and follow his guidelines, but this is not related to my question, which is how to avoid monolithic actions/reducers files.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a feature store for a feature that already has a store? Does it even make any sense?" do you mean that you want to create nested reducers?

Comment: To answer your subsequent question. 
Avoiding is big reducers and actions could also play a role in how you are organizing your structure.
You need to try and flatten as best as you can, and separate your concerns. You might not get to a `n` degree because it's also based on your business requirements